# how to typescript eslint and prettier

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

My `package.json`

```
    "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
```

My `prettierrc`

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true
}
```

And `eslintrc.json` file

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "prettier"],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 13,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", "tab"],
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"],
        "semi": ["error", "always"]
    }
}
```

I want to configure my project with ESLint and Prettier, to validate (or fix) code.
But I can't configure to check naming convention, also want to check file name

I tried installing `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` but is not in the npm registry, and then tried

`npm i eslint-ts-naming-convention -D`

And got this:

> ERR_PNPM_FETCH_404  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@hjcostabr76%2Fgenerics: Not Found - 404
> This error happened while installing the dependencies of eslint-ts-naming-convention@2.0.1-beta
> @hjcostabr76/generics is not in the npm registry, or you have no permission to fetch it.
> An authorization header was used: Bearer 883e[hidden]

This is my current code and file, and I want this to throw error

```
// filename: foo_name.ts
export class nameExample_Foo {
    ThisIs_InValidName() {
        return { foo: 1 };
    }
}
```

Class must be written in `pascalcase` and function `camelcase`.

Comment: Check the the [`file-names` plugin](https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames)

Comment: Also `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` is a rule not a plugin :)